# Utility object for setTimeout

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, timer

I was using setTimeouts for a project where a callback will be called after a duration, but the user has the options of extending, pausing or stopping the timeout. I felt using the default setTimeout was a bit clunky, especially since I needed to remember the timeout ids, and I decided to create a timeout utility object. I was wondering if I'm doing this properly, and whether you could give me some tips on how to refactor my code?

**Object definition**

```
//Utility object that makes it easier to control timeouts
function Timer(duration, callback) {
    this._duration = duration;
    this._callback = callback;
    this._id = -1;

    this._paused = true;
    this._lastRunTime = -1;
    this._remainingTime = this._duration;
}

//calls the current timeout; if a function is passed, run that function
//instead of default callback (but do not change the default callback)
Timer.prototype.callTimer = function(aCallback, aDuration) {
    var that = this,
        //sets callback and duration to default values if not passed in
        callback = aCallback || this._callback,
        duration = aDuration || this._duration;

    //if a previous timeout has been set, clear it
    if (this._id > -1 ) {
        clearTimeout(this._id);
    }
    //executes the callback and resets the timer
    this._id = setTimeout(function() {
        callback();
        that.resetTimer();
    }, duration);

    this._paused = false;
    //rememebers the time when the timer was run (for pauseTimer)
    this._lastRunTime = new Date();
}

Timer.prototype.resetTimer = function() {
    this._remainingTime = this._duration;
    this._paused = true;
    this._lastRunTime = -1;
    clearTimeout(this._id);
}

//changes the default callback
//if second argument is true, execute callTimer
Timer.prototype.changeCallback = function(callback, callTimer) {
    this._callback = callback;
    if (callTimer) this.callTimer();
}

Timer.prototype.pauseTimer = function() {
    if (this._lastRunTime === -1) {
        throw new Error('Timer has not been run yet');
    }

    //if currently paused, call timer with remaining time left
    if (this._paused) {
        this._lastRunTime = new Date();
        this.callTimer(this._callback, this._remainingTime);
    } 
    //else pause
    else {
        clearTimeout(this._id);
        //subtract the amount of time that has elapsed 
        this._remainingTime -= (new Date() - this._lastRunTime);
    }

    //toggles the _paused variable
    this._paused = !this._paused;
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/6nhGW/

**Test Code**

```
var button = document.getElementById('extendTimeout'),
    button2 = document.getElementById('tempChangeCallback'),            
    button3 = document.getElementById('changeCallback'),
    button4 = document.getElementById('resetTimer'),    
    button5 = document.getElementById('pauseTimer'),        
    startTime,
    timeout = -1;

var timer = new Timer(3000, function() {
    console.log('Total time elapsed: ' + (new Date() - startTime));
    startTime = null;    
})

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (!startTime) startTime = new Date();
    timer.callTimer();
})

button2.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (!startTime) startTime = new Date();    
    timer.callTimer(function() {
        console.log('Temporarily change callback');
        console.log('Total time elapsed: ' + (new Date() - startTime));
        startTime = null;
    });
})

button3.addEventListener('click', function() {
    timer.changeCallback(function() {
        console.log('Callback has been changed!');
        startTime = null;
    }, true);
});

button4.addEventListener('click', function() {
    timer.resetTimer();
    startTime = null;
});

button5.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (!startTime) startTime = new Date();    
    timer.pauseTimer();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a once over:

- I would not use `_` to prefix all your variables, it would make more sense to either actually use private variables or write a comment that this variables should not be touched by callers
- `pauseTimer` lies, since you toggle. I would call it `toggleTimer` or `startStopTimer`
- Your code is well commented except for `//toggles the _paused variable` which is kind of obvious ;)
- Besides some missing semicolons, your code looks fine on JsHint.com
- I think in `callTimer` you could have called your paramater `callback`, then do `callback = callback || this.callback` and then use `callback` in your closure.

All in all, good, re-usable code.

For my own purposes I would probably make the private variables really private and move the functions out of `prototype` into the constructor. That would increase memory footprint, but I would never use more than a dozen of these at the same time.

Comment: @konijin Thank you for your comments, and it's really helpful! I considered using private variables but decided against it due to the increased memory footprint, but you make a good point that we don't really need too many of them around.

Comment: On overriding the callback in callTime, I don't fully understand what you mean - do you mean that we shouldn't do callback = callback || this.callback, and instead do this.callback = callback || this.callback? The only problem is this would overwrite the default callback that we set initially?

Comment: Yes, the default would be changed, I guess if you call it 3 times with a different callback that it would not make sense to change `this.callback`, will update my question.